# how can I create a matrix of double with alglib?

Tags: c++, matrix, alglib

I need to create a matrix with alglib because I need to use a function contained in the library, but I need my matrix to contain element of type double (or something similar to double implemented in alglib)
how can I do it?

if it is not possible does someone knows a library that implments the SVD function even for matrix of type double?

I'm using c++.

thank you

Answer (score 8):

For the current release of alglib as of writing, a 2D matrix of double precision values can be created as follows:

```
ap::real_2d_array matrix;
double data[4] = {0.1, 0.2,
                  0.3, 0.4};
matrix.setcontent(1, 2, 1, 2, data);
```

The matrix produced by the code would appear as:

```
0.1  0.2

0.3  0.4
```

The *setcontent* function is what determines the dimensions and content of the matrix. It has the following definition:

```
setcontent(int row_start_index, int row_end_index, int col_start_index, int col_end_index, data)
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to set the dimensions of the matrix without filling it with data, you could use the following:

```
setbounds(int row_start_index, int row_end_index, int col_start_index, int col_end_index)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the manual it's written:

> ALGLIB (ap.h header) defines several "basic" datatypes (types which are used by all packages) and many package-specific datatypes. "Basic" datatypes are:
>
> alglib::ae_int_t - signed integer type used by library
>
> alglib::complex - double precision complex datatype, safer replacement
>   for std::complex
>
> alglib::ap_error - exception which is thrown by library
>
> boolean_1d_array - 1-dimensional boolean array
>
> integer_1d_array - 1-dimensional integer array
>
> real_1d_array - 1-dimensional real (double precision) array
>
> complex_1d_array - 1-dimensional complex array
>
> boolean_2d_array - 2-dimensional boolean array
>
> integer_2d_array - 2-dimensional integer array
>
> **real_2d_array - 2-dimensional real (double precision) array**
>
> complex_2d_array - 2-dimensional complex array

The rest should be pretty straightforward.

This should create a 2x2 matrix:

```
alglib::real_2d_array r2("[[1.1,2.2],[3.3,4.4]]");
```

result:

```
1.1  2.2

3.3  4.4
```